# Passing two params on angular js url using app states js and view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to pass two params on the url using angular js,
I declared these parameters on both my app.states.js and the view like the following, but it doesn't work, so is there any other solution with my architecture.

Thanks in advance.

PS : the two params are : idCol and idForm.

app.states.js

```
 .state("restricted.forms.my_formulaire", {
                url: "/my_formulaire/{IdCol:[0-9]{1,4}}/{IdForm:[0-9]{1,4}}",
                templateUrl: 'app/views/my_formulaireView.html',
                controller: 'my_formulaireCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load('app/Controllers/my_formulaireController.js');
                    }]
                },
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'my Formulaire'
                }
            })
```

myView.html

```
<div class="description" ng-show="lstForms.length != 0">
  <div class="md-card uk-margin-medium-bottom">
      <div class="md-card-content">
          <div class="uk-overflow-container">
              <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th id="formulaire_on">Formulaire</th>
                      <th id="fo_option">Option</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr class="formulaire_option" ng-repeat="(k,l) in lstForms">
                      <td>{{l.f_name}}</td>
                      <td>
                       <a ui-sref="restricted.forms.my_formulaire({IdCol:l.f_fk_collecte_id})({IdForm:l.f_id})"><i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                       <a ng-click="DeleteForm(k,l)"><i class="md-icon material-icons">delete_sweep</i></a>
                       <a ng-click="copyForm(l)"><i class="md-icon material-icons">content_copy</i></a>
                      </td>

                  </tr>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the 2 variables to `ui-sref` like this:

```
<a ui-sref="restricted.forms.my_formulaire({ IdCol: l.f_fk_collecte_id, IdForm: l.f_id })">
    <i class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE254;</i>
</a>
```